# Xcode6 not showing crash stacktrace / code

Tags: ios, xcode6

Xcode 6.1.1 (iOS 8.1)

Since a few days whenever I'm running an app in debug modus and it crashed (for some reason) I don't see any viable messages why the crash occurred.

[image: Xcode6 screenshot]

Normally Xcode would automatically jump to the desired file + line and give me additional crash information in my console.
But besides the above screenshot nothing happens, not even when I press the "Continue program execution" breakpoint button in the bottom part of the screen.

What I've tried:
- Enabling/disabling breakpoints 
- Enabling/disabling "All Exceptions" breakpoints
- Enabling/disabling zombie objects

But nothing seems to work. And it doesn't matter which crash or exception the app throws.

**UPDATE**:
When I run the app in the simulator the console shows me the correct error, e.g:

```
2014-12-09 12:55:34.880 xxx[30965:1578001] -[MainViewController _methodNotAvaiable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdb92f32390
```

However running it from a connect device does not trigger that console log

Comment: It seems there is something wrong with the interface orientation methods. Are you using supportedInterfaceOrientations methods in your VC?

Comment: Yeah I figured out what the problem was, but fixing this bug is not why I started this question. I wonder why I can't seem to see any logs in my console.

Comment: go to xcode breakpoints and at bottom plus button is there click on that to add exception breakpoint so that you can access the line of crash

Comment: @NarasimhaiahKolli: Tried that, no effect.